# Why does my answer get spammed

Tags: support

My question is about this answer of mine: https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/600/122

It frequently gets edited by bots, replacing the content by stupid advertising. It's not a problem, because the edit always gets declined, but I get "spammed" with notifications.

I don't know where I can see declined edits for an answer, but here are some examples:

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12986
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12388
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12243
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10646
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10554
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13092

Are there other answers that are edited frequently? Is there a possibility to prevent that (like locking the answer)?

Comment: related [Automatically reject suggested edits where edit summary is an email address](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208774)

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, spam edits on posts on SE are far from uniformly distributed. Spammers tend to identify a small number of posts which they want to target and direct most of their edits on those posts. Your question is very likely one of these spam edit magnets. I don't think any particular criteria for a post being targeted are known to anyone except the spammers and possibly SE employees. (There is some source where SE employees discussed this, perhaps on one of the meta sites, but I can't seem to find it now.)

SE is aware of the existence of such posts, and in fact is quite interested in identifying such posts, which are useful for calibrating their spam filters. Unfortunately, there's not really much that you can or should do; your post will probably keep attracting spam edits for a while. You could disassociate the post from your account by contacting SE (to stop getting notified about every spam edit suggestion), or you could have a mod lock the post, but both of these have negative consequences. It's easier for the analytics to identify such edits with longer answers, so elongating your answer (as a mod has already done) will probably reduce the number of spam edits which make it through to the review queue. You don't really need to worry though; such obvious spam edits will essentially never be approved, so the worst thing that happens is you get some irrelevant notifications.

Answer (score 1):

We can lock the answer if that's what you wish, but that will also prevent voting on it ("Lock" is a nuclear shutdown option). If you wish that, simply flag the answer with a custom flag and ask for that to happen (link to this post too, for context).

I have notified our Stack Exchange overlords with this.

Answer (score 0):

Add 3000 invisible characters to the end of the post, for example by typing `&#8203;` over and over.  That should get these edits automatically rejected as vandalism.  It's worked for me in the past on other SE sites.

(You can copy and paste the extra characters from this answer.) ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​